# On Premise NPS server check computer account in Azure AD

Tags: certificate, entra-id, radius, nps

I've got a Windows based NPS Radius server for authenticating my wireless clients based on device certificates (supplied by my internal CA). In my NPS network policy I have set conditions to grant access only when that the computer is a member of the group Domain Computers, the computer account not disabled etc.
We are slowly shifting towards Azure AD, meaning computers are no longer a member of our on premise AD.
I found this article https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-nps-extension but this only for authenticating users through Azure AD, not computers.
Is there something similar available so my on-premise NPS server can validate the Azure AD joined computers in Azure?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're going pure cloud machines, then there's no official Microsoft support as far as I know for this yet.

If you google hard enough, there is an unofficial workaround that works by creating dummy duplicate AAD machines to the local AD.